# Tool to Migrate from SVN to TFS

Tags: svn, tfs, migration, tfs-migration

Can anyone suggest a tool for migrating from SVN to TFS? Preferably this would be Open Source.

Comment: You can try out:-
http://www.persistentsys.com/CompetencyCenters/Microsoft/MicrosoftTFSMigrationToolforSubversion/tabid/307/Default.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try the codeplex project [SVN to TFS Migration Tool](http://www.codeplex.com/MigrationSyncToolkit/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=78).

Comment: That is a link to a feature request, not the project itself!

  "I'd like to create a CodePlex project for a SVN to TFS tool, and if there is enough interest I'll create it."

Answer (score 15):

Seeing as the codeplex project that was accepted as the original answer has now closed down, I thought it would be useful to note that Microsoft has a number of conversion tools listed here: [Source control migration tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb840033.aspx).

Comment: This must be a joke.  SVNtoTFS tool costs: 1 Module and 10 hours of support $1995

Comment: @Talon you wont be in the repo migration tool business for very long with a different business model. How many times will the average organization move/migrate any repo within ANY time period?

Answer (score 3):

Try this link that offers a free solution by migrating:

SVN -> GIT -> TFS

http://www.incyclesoftware.com/2013/08/migrate-svn-to-tfs-its-free/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look at this discussion: [this discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsversioncontrol/thread/dafc9550-1c17-40ae-ad0a-fc463b336507/). Two tools are named in it. My experience with migrating the other way was very bad, by the way. Getting your history out of TFS is very difficult and requires custom coding. Just so you know.

Answer (score -1):

You can try out:

- [www.kyrosoft.com/products/index2.html](http://www.kyrosoft.com/products/index2.html)
- [www.microsoft.com/india/vsts/third_party_products.aspx](http://www.microsoft.com/india/vsts/third_party_products.aspx)