# How can my team migrate easily from Visual SVN to TFS 2010?

Tags: svn, version-control, tfs

My team has been using Visual SVN for source code control, and we plan to migrate to TFS 2010, however we still want seamless access to old projects and thier source code and change history.  Also we have several projects that weren't .NET based and were developed in C in a 3rd party IDE.  Is there an easy way to unify our systems? If not is there a way we can teach only one of the 2 tools and use them transparently? (IE, use something in TFS to connect to subversion, or use SVN to connect to TFS without losing features of TFS?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tool to Migrate from SVN to TFS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/536564/tool-to-migrate-from-svn-to-tfs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a migration tool over at codeplex. It should take every SVN change and put it into TFS.
http://svn2tfs.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

> or use SVN to connect to TFS without losing features of TFS?

There is [svnbridge](http://svnbridge.codeplex.com/) which translates requests from SVN clients into TFS API calls. But obviously this will not expose any TFS-specific features which have no counterpart in SVN, as an SVN client cannot know about those.